# How to reformat the resultant excel sheet after coming multiple excel sheet in Pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I tried combining multiple sheets of multiple excel into single excel using pandas python but in the end excel sheet,the rows labels are the excel sheet file name,each sheet as column name.I am getting it as messy.

How do I get it in proper format.Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

os.chdir("C:/Users/w8/PycharmProjects/decorators_exaample/excel_files")

path = "C:/Users/w8/PycharmProjects/decorators_exaample/excel_files"
files = os.listdir(path)

AllFiles = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    info = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
    AllFiles=AllFiles.append(info, ignore_index=True)



writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Final.xlsx")
AllFiles.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

The final excel looks like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RdaX.png)

Answer (score 0):

you don't actually need the whole os and Workbook part. That could clean your code and ease finding errors. I assume, that `path` is the path to the folder where all the excel files are stored:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = "C:\Users\w8\PycharmProjects\decorators_exaample\excel_files"
file_list = glob.glob(path)

df= pd.DataFrame()

for f in file_list :
    info = pd.read_excel(f)
    df = df.append(info)

df.to_excel('C:\Users\w8\PycharmProjects\decorators_exaample\excel_files\new_filename.xlsx')
```

should be as easy as that

Comment: The backslash was causing the problem.I tried forwardslash but I am getting this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/w8/PycharmProjects/decorators_exaample/decorator_example.py", line 10, in <module>
    info = pd.read_excel(f)
  File "C:\Users\w8\PycharmProjects\decorators_exaample\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\w8\PycharmProjects\decorators_exaample\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 824, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self

Comment: So is your problem solved? Did you try the suggested solution? If so does it work for you?

Comment: No It didnt.Anyhow my senior said I will look into it.Thanks for the answer man @TiTo